# Property 'self.readCount' not initialized at super.init call

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following class

// LearningItem

```
class LearningItem : NSObject {
    var id: String
    var title: String
    var subtitle: String?
    var image: String
    var uploadDate: Int

    init(id: String, title: String, image: String, uploadDate: Int) {
        self.id = id
        self.title = title
        self.image = image
        self.uploadDate = uploadDate
    }
```

I have another class

// Book.swift

```
class Book: LearningItem {
    var publishDate: String?
    var author: String?
    var mediaUrl: String?
    var video : String?
    var tags: [String]?
    var lists: [String: AnyObject]?
    var readCount: Int
    var categories: [String]?
    var courses: [String]?
    var amazonBuyUrl: String?
    var starCount: Int
    var read: Bool?
    var completed = [String : Int]()
    var stars = [String : Int]()
    var completedDate : Int?

    var desc: String
    var epub: String
    var authorDesc: String

    init(id: String, title: String, desc: String, authorDesc: String, image: String, epub: String, readCount: Int, uploadDate: Int, starCount: Int) {

        super.init(id: id, title: title, image: image, uploadDate: uploadDate)

        self.id = id
        self.desc = desc
        self.authorDesc = authorDesc
        self.title = title
        self.epub = epub
        self.image = image
        self.readCount = readCount
        self.uploadDate = uploadDate
        self.starCount = starCount
    }
```

I get the error "Property 'self.readCount' not initialized at super.init call"

where I call "super.init(id: id, title: title, image: image, uploadDate: uploadDate)" in Book.swift

Comment: makes readCount optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class initialisation not finished until it's designated initializers
 not  finished with initializing all properties 
and after that you can call super class's designated initializers

> Designated initializers are the primary initializers for a class. A designated initializer fully initializes all properties introduced by that class and calls an appropriate superclass initializer to continue the initialization process up the superclass chain.

SO

> Class initialization in Swift is a two-phase process. In the first phase, each stored property is assigned an initial value by the class that introduced it. Once the initial state for every stored property has been determined, the second phase begins, and each class is given the opportunity to customize its stored properties further before the new instance is considered ready for use.

apple docs https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html

so

```
class Book: LearningItem {
    var publishDate: String?
    var author: String?
    var mediaUrl: String?
    var video : String?
    var tags: [String]?
    var lists: [String: AnyObject]?
    var readCount: Int
    var categories: [String]?
    var courses: [String]?
    var amazonBuyUrl: String?
    var starCount: Int
    var read: Bool?
    var completed = [String : Int]()
    var stars = [String : Int]()
    var completedDate : Int?

    var desc: String
    var epub: String
    var authorDesc: String

    init(id: String, title: String, desc: String, authorDesc: String, image: String, epub: String, readCount: Int, uploadDate: Int, starCount: Int) {

        self.readCount = readCount
        self.starCount = starCount
        self.desc = desc
        self.epub = epub
        self.authorDesc = authorDesc

        super.init(id: id, title: title, image: image, uploadDate: uploadDate)


    }
}
```

Comment: Consider that the assignments after calling `super` are redundant.

Comment: @vadian Sorry Didn't get your point ,  Can you please explain this.

Comment: You can delete the 4 lines after `super.init...` because the properties are initialized in the superclass and therefore also available in the subclass.